# wge100 (Global Shutter Ethernet Camera) how can I buy them?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that the camera_drivers stack has support for Willow Garage's wge100 Global Shutter Ethernet Cameras that come on the PR2's arms. Does any one know which cameras are these (hardware-wise)? or How can one buy them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10670/wge100-(global-shutter-ethernet-camera)-how-can-i-buy-them?/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wge100 cameras were developed at Willow for the PR2.  We do not sell them individually.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-07-20**:
I'm sure they could turn into an individual product that Willow Garage could sell to poor people who cannot afford a PR2.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-12-25**:
Hi can ı ask something about ricoh theta cameras. Is it compatible with ros? or whic 360 degree cameras compatible with ros? thank you